# Login with MVC using SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sqlclient

I am using the default MVC package that you start with when you make a new project. I added this code to my Login script, after they click the submit button, it will attempt to log him in and it wouldn't allow me to make this User.Identity.IsAuthenticated work, so I can fire off certain things after he has successfully logged in.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server=server; database=db; user id=user; password=password"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE [UserName] = @param1 AND [PasswordField] = @param2 AND [Active] = 1", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Clear();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", model.UserName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", model.Password);
                SqlDataReader adapter = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (adapter.Read())
                {
                    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.UserName };
                    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", "Index");
        }
    }
```

If he is logged in I want to do something like

```
public ActionResult IsAuthenicated()
{
     if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
         //go to new screen
     }
     else
     {
         //return back to login screen
     }
}
```

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?  Additionally, is there a reason you want to implement your own authentication system instead of using something like ASPNet Identity?

Comment: @BrendanGreen. I would want to use ASPNet Identity, but the my issue is I don't know how to link a database to it so it can verify the login to my table.

Comment: Start here: http://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: One more thing, if you're using MVC4 or later, use "RedirectToLocal" after your successful login (instead of "RedirectToAction") to prevent cross-site hacks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it could be called *reliable*, meaning: you can probably log in.

On the other hand it doesn't seem at all **secure**: that SQL query implies you are storing the password in the clear. At the very least you should [hash and salt all passwords](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

There are many pluggable auth systems such as ASP.Net Membership (old now but still works) or ASP.Net Identity (new) that take care of the heavylifting for you.

Comment: What is all needed to make the user fully logged in? I finally got no more exceptions or errors during the login, I check my database and if that username and password are correct and if they are, I will add him to the list as a correct signinuser and sign him in. After it spins around and logs him in. I click the button that requires if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) is true and it doesn't work.